# Finding max, second max, and third max aggregated by two parameters in R or with R's sqldf

Tags: r, max, sqldf

So I am trying to find the max, second max, and third max water use per customer ID per year for a dataset. I'm using R and the sqldf library, but am open to any R solutions to this. Here's a bit of sample data:

```
 Year  | ID | Month  | Use |
----------------------------
2009    101 1   103

2009    101 2   209

2009    101 3   375

2009    101 4   360

2010    101 1   170

2010    101 2   381

2010    101 3   275

2010    101 4   260

2009    102 1   263

2009    102 2   234

2009    102 3   45

2009    102 4   275

2010    102 1   469

2010    102 2   107

2010    102 3   354

2010    102 4   436
```

Ideally I would want to return three matrices, `max1`, `max2`, `max3` with columns `ID`, `Year`, `Max` (or second max or third max, respectively)
So  `max1 = [101, 2009, 375, 101, 2010, 381, 102, 2009, 275, 102, 2010, 469]` etc.

My initial approach was to make a nested for loop with `listofIDs` and `listofYears` as the domains of `ID` and `Year`, like:

```
for i in 1:length(listofIDs){

for y in 1:length(listofYears){

monthlylist<-sqldf("select Month, Use from Dataframe where ID=listofIDs[i] and Year=listofYears[y]")
```

and then sort `monthlylist` and pull out the max's, etc.
But `sqldf` won't read variables like that so I would have to explicitly state where `ID = 101`, where `ID = 102` each time.

Any ideas on how to get sqldf to recognize my varibles, or a better way to find the max, second max, and third max aggregated by year and ID? I am working with big datasets so ideally something that doesn't take forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code creates a list of three data frames (`dat` is your original data frame):

```
lapply(seq(3), function(x)
  aggregate(Use ~ Year + ID, dat, function(y)
    y[order(-y)][x]))
```

The result:

```
[[1]]
  Year  ID Use
1 2009 101 375
2 2010 101 381
3 2009 102 275
4 2010 102 469

[[2]]
  Year  ID Use
1 2009 101 360
2 2010 101 275
3 2009 102 263
4 2010 102 436

[[3]]
  Year  ID Use
1 2009 101 209
2 2010 101 260
3 2009 102 234
4 2010 102 354
```

---

*How it works*:

The function `lapply` is used to apply another function multiple times. The command `seq(3)` generates a vector of numbers from 1 to 3. The parameter `x` represents one of these numbers. The function `aggregate` is used to apply another function to the `Use` values grouped by `Year` and `ID`. The parameter `y` represents the `Use` values in one group. The command `y[order(-y)]` sorts the `Use` values in descending order. Afterwards, `[x]` is used to extract the first, second, and third element, respectively, of this ordered vector.

Comment: Thanks! This does give the right answer. If you have time, can you explain how this works? I am fairly new to R and tried to look at the documentation for the functions you're using but I'm still a little lost.
 
Additionally, to get the min, second min and third min, would you change the y[order(-y)][x] to y[order(y)][x] ? (Just a guess)

Comment: @user2930124 You're right. The command `order` arranges values in ascending order. Due to the `-`, values are arranged in descending order.

Comment: @user2930124 I added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

First set up the test data in easily reproducible form:

```
# set up test data

Lines <- "Year ID Month Use
2009 101 1 103
2009 101 2 209
2009 101 3 375
2009 101 4 360
2010 101 1 170
2010 101 2 381
2010 101 3 275
2010 101 4 260
2009 102 1 263
2009 102 2 234
2009 102 3 45
2009 102 4 275
2010 102 1 469
2010 102 2 107
2010 102 3 354
2010 102 4 436
"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Now that we have the input data here are some approaches:

**1) sqldf/SQLite** The following three SQL statements should calculate these quantities.  If they run too slowly you could try adding a Year, ID index.  Note that the three SQL statements are the same except for the `from` clauses:

Now create the three data frames:

```
library(sqldf)

max1 <- sqldf("select Year, ID, max(Use) Use 
   from DF 
   group by Year, ID") 

max2 <- sqldf("select Year, ID, max(Use) Use 
   from (select Year, ID, Use from DF 
         except select * from max1) 
   group by Year, ID")

max3 <- sqldf("select Year, ID, max(Use) Use 
   from (select Year, ID, Use from DF 
         except select * from max1 
         except select * from max2) 
   group by Year, ID")
```

**2) sqldf/PostgreSQL** The above is for sqldf with sqlite but it is even easier with sqldf and PostgreSQL because then we could use PostgreSQL's `rank()` windowing function.  (There is more info on using PostgreSQL with sqldf [here](https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#12._How_does_one_use_sqldf_with_PostgreSQL?).)

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(sqldf)

DF2 <- sqldf('select *, rank() over (partition by "Year", "ID" order by "Use" desc) 
              from "DF"')
split(DF2[1:4], DF2$rank)[1:3]
```

The last line could alternately be replaced with this:

```
lapply(1:3, function(r) subset(DF2, rank == r)[1:4])
```

If we wanted a pure SQL solution then:

```
max1 <- sqldf('select "Year", "ID", "Month", "Use" from "DF2" where "rank" = 1')
max2 <- sqldf('select "Year", "ID", "Month", "Use" from "DF2" where "rank" = 2')
max3 <- sqldf('select "Year", "ID", "Month", "Use" from "DF2" where "rank" = 3')
```

or to produce a list of data frames:

```
lapply(1:3, function(r) 
   fn$sqldf('select "Year", "ID", "Month", "Use" from "DF2" where "rank" = $r'))
```

**3) ave** Its not so hard doing this in straight R.  Here the Rank 1's are the largest, the Rank 2's the second largest, etc. so we just split on `Rank` as in the prior solution and take the first three components:

```
Rank <- with(DF, ave(-Use, Year, ID, FUN = rank))
split(DF, Rank)[1:3]
```

This would also work in place of the last line:

```
lapply(1:3, function(r) subset(DF, Rank == r))
```

which returns a list whose components are the three data frames.

UPDATE: Wrote out the second solution too.